# Test case with coroutine not getting complete code coverage

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit

I am using viewModelScope.launch for a method which updated DB, my unit test case is passing but the code coverage is only partial, sonar shows the line of code with viewModel.launch(dispatcher.IO) is not covered. Following is my method

```
fun deleteItemFromDb(s: String) = viewModelScope.launch(dispatchersProvider.IO){ 
    repository.deleteItem(s)
}
```

Please help

Comment: do you mean the main Thread finishes before your IO coroutine finishes and so a part of the database is not updated? if yes, you need to call .join() at the point you want to wait for the db update to finish. this will wait til the deleteItemFromDb is finished and then carries on with the Main Thread.
you may also need to make some functions suspended or use runBlocking {} accordingly.
if you share some more code of the part you are calling this method, helping will be easier.